# Openlayers tiles source with poor resolution, how zoom out?

Tags: openlayers-2, tiles, resolution, wmts

I am using Openlayers to display a map from Vienna Open Data ([Capabilities](http://www.wien.gv.at/wmts/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml)) in an app for mobiles, which have higher DPI screens. 
The resolution of the tiles is not so good (I suppose because they are JPEG instead of PNG).

Is it possible to use the tiles from the upper zoom level as if they where smaller tiles for the current level, faking the resolution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Client Zoom Feature`.  OpenLayers stretches the layer div when the resolution is not supported by that layer's tile service.

http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13.1/examples/clientzoom.html

Comment: AFAIK the client zoom is used to fake intermediate zoom levels that are missing. I tried that, when I zoom out all is well until I reach the next zoom level, then the bad resolution comes again. I would like to use the tiles of level x on level x-1, zoomed to 50% (thus increasing the resolution by factor 2)

Comment: Then You need to use http://www.maptiler.org, it will break the images into smaller tiles for each zoom level and serve them separately.

Comment: You mean using local tiles? That is not an option because of device constraints for the size of the app.

Comment: Tiles will be on server not on client. Client requests tile on the area it is viewing.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. How can I use maptiler.org with an existing map service, to which I have no access to?

Comment: the secret is to uses this config for the layer: transitionEffect: 'resize'